# Struts2 seo-friendly url?

Tags: rest, struts2, clean-urls

Instead of

```
Users.action?login=foo
```

I want to have

```
/users/foo/
```

In spring mvc they have "URI templates" for it, but they are only annotation-based.
Is it possible to do such url-s in Struts with xml from-the-box?

The only one thing I found was external tool: http://www.progbear.com/voice/2010/struts-2-create-friendly-url-with-urlrewritefilter

wildcards in struts do not work with "/" and cannot pass parameters to action.

Sure I can get this info from request but I believe Struts should support it.

Comment: use can use convention plugin for struts2 but again thats a annotation based functionality.in my view turkey url rewriting what you mentioned in your post is bets bet to go..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this out-of-the-box with Struts2. Check out the `NamedVariablePatternMatcher`, which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772737/hidden-features-of-struts-2-framework/4837917#4837917).

In your case, you would need to enable the options in the answer that I linked to above and then map your action as:

```
<action name="users/{login}" class="...">
    ...
</action>
```

You could also look into the [rest plug-in](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/rest-plugin.html).